# How to decrease validation_loss and increase accuracy for age prediction?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am new to machine learning and I try to train a model to predict the age of a person in an image.I trained my model on 4 age classes (0-18, 18-40, 40-65, 65+). My biggest problem is that I don't know how to optimize. I put the code below and some results. I trained the model on 10k images, the validation set has around 3.5k images and the test set has around 3k images. I used a pre-learned model as a base model, namely 'Mobilenet', batch size = 32, epochs = 100, dropout=.4. I tried to update the learning rate, every 10 epochs in which the model failed to decrease validation_loss, learning rate halved (we start from the value 0.001). I would expect the accuracy to be better for such a prediction, and validation_loss much lower (validation_loss is around 1 for me).[image with results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kAWJ.png)

Any suggestion is welcome.

```
if self.model_type == 'Mobilenet':
            base_model = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.MobileNet(include_top=False, input_shape=img_shape,
                                                                   pooling='max', weights='imagenet', dropout=.4)
        x = base_model.output
        x = keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001)(x)
        x = Dense(self.neurons_a, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=123))(x)
        x = Dropout(rate=dropout, seed=123)(x)
        output = Dense(self.class_count, activation='softmax',
                       kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=123))(x)
        model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=output)
        model.compile(Adamax(lr=self.lr), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=self.metrics)
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are using the code I created, probably got it from Kaggle I surmise. The model appears to be behaving well with very high training accuracy and no signs of over fitting. It is common for the validation loss to stabilize around some value as your plot demonstrates. Only other thing I can think of is to evaluate the balance of your data set. By that I mean look at the number of samples you have in the training set for each class. I expect you will have a significant imbalance with significantly few samples in the 65+ class. In this case there are several mitigation strategies. The simplest is to use the class_weights parameter in model.fit. To do that you need to create a class_weights dictionary. The process to do that is outline below

```
Lets say your class distribution is
 0-18 - 500 samples
 18-40- 2000 samples
 40-65 - 1500 samples
 65+ - 200 samples
Then your dictionary would be
class_weights={0: 2000/500, 1:2000/2000, 2: 2000/1500, 3: 2000/200}
in model.fit set class_weight=class_weights
```

My experience is this generally only results in a slight improvement. There are several other approaches like creating "augented" images using say cv2 or PIL and storing these augmented images in the under represented class directories. You may want to utilize a module smote to help if you have an imbalanced data set. A tutorial on that is located [here.](https://machinelearningmastery.com/smote-oversampling-for-imbalanced-classification/) You can tell a lot more about how your model is performing if you create a confusion matrix. You can use the validation set for that if you do not have a test set. Did you use generators to input your data to the model? The code below shows how to create a confusion matrix. I assume that somewhere in your code you are able to provide the labels for your validation or test set. If you used a generator and set shuffle=False you can get the labels from your generator from labels-gen.labels. Then use code below

```
preds=model.predict(test_gen, batch_size=test_batch_size, verbose=0, steps=None)
labels=test_gen.labels # make sure shuffle=False in the generator
y_pred=[]
classes=['0-18', '18-40', '40-65', '65+']
for i, p in enumerate(preds):
    pred_index=np.argmax(p)
    y_pred.append(pred_index)
y_true= np.array(labels)        
y_pred=np.array(y_pred)   
cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred )
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, vmin=0, fmt='g', cmap='Blues', cbar=False)       
plt.xticks(np.arange(length)+.5, classes, rotation= 90)
plt.yticks(np.arange(length)+.5, classes, rotation=0)
plt.xlabel("Predicted")
plt.ylabel("Actual")
plt.title("Confusion Matrix")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes, i am using the code from kaggle, i am trying to learn more about this topic. Yes, i am reducing the learning rate, I understand that the validation_loss stabilizes / tends to a value but it is normal to be this high?

Comment: see modified answer - only thing I can think of is to determine the balance of your dataset, that is compare the number of image samples in each class. If there is a significant imbalance then use the code in the modified answer.

Comment: I am using generators to input data to the model. I never thought about the imbalance between the samples, now that you are saying this I can tell this is a problem. Thanks a lot for the suggestions, I will definitely apply them!